# One way network bridge

Tags: networking, bridge

I have two networks, with a single machine sitting on both (two NICs) shown below.  That machine is Linux.  I was hoping to set up a bridge of some sort so that work stations on the 192.168.1.x network could access the network of 10.x.x.x.  The 10.x.x.x network has many file servers and machines that the workstations on 192 would want to access.

Is it possible to set up something on the dual NIC server so a workstation on 192 could enter 10.1.1.56 for an IP and see that machine which resides on the 10.x.x.x network?  Does this type of bridge have a name/description that I can google on?  I do not need 127 machines to see the 192 network (except the dual nic server), in fact I would prefer if they didn't (one way).

More info: the 192 machines are both windows and Linux.  It would be great if I can also bridge from 192.168.1.x to 10.x.x.x using the hostname of the 10.x.x.x machine, but if we need to stick to just IP address that would be ok.

Note:  I meant 10.x.x.x, not 127.x.x.x
[image: Network]

Comment: You're not actually using `127.x.x.x` IPs as a network are you?

Comment: You're right, I am use 10.x.x.x, just had a moment of stupidity.

Comment: Uh, do you mean a router?

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is a router.  A router will connect to layer 2 networks and route traffic between them.   Commercial grade routers also allow you to configure access control lists to limit what traffic can go from one network to another.

If you set up a DNS server or configure your local host file, you can use hostnames instead of IP addresses.

One other thing:  the entire 127.0.0.0/8 network is reserved for a loopback address.  You should use a different IP address block, like 192.168.2.0/24.